# Parse 0x format string to bytes swift

Tags: swift, string

I need to change 
This (string):

```
"0xab,0xcd,0x00,0x01,0xff,0xff,0xab,0xcd,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x10,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00"
```

to (bytes)

```
[0xab,0xcd,0x00,0x01,0xff,0xff,0xab,0xcd,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x10,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 ]
```

using swift

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to remove the `0x` from each string, then split the remaining comma separated values into an array. Finally, use `flatMap` to convert each hex string into a number.

```
// Your original string
let hexString = "0xab,0xcd,0x00,0x01,0xff,0xff,0xab,0xcd,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x10,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00"
// Remove all of the "0x"
let cleanString = hexString.replacingOccurrences(of: "0x", with: "")
// Create an array of hex strings
let hexStrings = cleanString.components(separatedBy: ",")
// Convert the array of hex strings into bytes (UInt8)
let bytes = hexStrings.flatMap { UInt8($0, radix: 16) }
```

I used `flatMap` in case there are any values that aren't valid hex byte values.